# How to build BQL statement to mix AND and OR

Tags: acumatica

I should I build my BQL statement to replicate this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 = 'X' AND 
(TABLE1.COL2 = 'Y' OR TABLE1.COL2 is null)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
PXSelect<TABLE1,
Where<TABLE1.col1, Equal<X>,
   And<Where<TABLE1.col2, Equal<Y>,
   Or<TABLE1.col2, IsNull>>>>>
```